# Why do stroked rectangles tend to go outside the canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've been experimenting with the <kbd><canvas></kbd> recently, and I noticed a strange behaviour when stroking rectangles *near the origin* **(0, 0)** of the canvas.

```js
// canvas context
var ctx = document.querySelector('#screen').getContext('2d');

// draw a rectangle
ctx.fillStyle = 'orange';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

// stroke a border for the rectangle
ctx.lineWidth = 20;
ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="screen"></canvas>
```

### What went wrong?

In the example above, the rectangle itself was drawn at **(0, 0)** as intended, but its border (the stroked rectangle) seems to be drawn at an offset.
Generally, when stroking a rectangle at a position away from the origin, this effect is omitted — 
Meaning that the stroked rectangles aren't being drawn starting at the position specified, but at an offset, I suppose. 

**Why is that?**

Comment: The canvas mechanism is weird. Lines are drawn along the coordinates but they "spread out" to either side of the median. (Maybe that's not "weird"; I don't do a lot of graphics work.)

Comment: @Pointy so at what position would I have to stroke the rectangles at to avoid this (for cases like the example above)?

Comment: Well for example if you want a 1-unit wide rectangle on the border of the canvas, you'd draw a rectangle 1/2 unit in from the edges, with a 1-unit-wide stroke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stroke is centered around the coordinates that your primitve is defined at. In the case of your rectangle with stroke width of `20`, drawing this at the top left of the canvas will cause half of the strokes width to be drawn outside of the canvas boundary.

Adjusting the coordinates of `strokeRect()` to `10,10,..` causes the rectangle to be offset from the canvas origin, meaning that the full stroke of `20` pixels will be visible from the top-left of the canvas:

```
ctx.lineWidth = 20;
ctx.strokeRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
```

Consider the following adjustments, made to ensure the stroke is fully visible around the drawn rectangle:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('#screen');

// Set the width and height to specify dimensions of canvas (in pixels)
// Choosing a 100x100 square matches the strokeRect() drawn below and
// therefore achieves the appearance of a symmetric stroke    
canvas.width = 100;
canvas.height = 100;

// canvas context
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// draw a rectangle
ctx.fillStyle = 'orange';
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 90, 90);

// stroke a border for the rectangle
ctx.lineWidth = 20;

var halfStroke = ctx.lineWidth * 0.5;

ctx.strokeRect(halfStroke, halfStroke, 100 - (halfStroke * 2), 100 - (halfStroke * 2));
```

```html
<canvas id="screen"></canvas>
```

#### Update

Here is a visualisation of the stroke in relation to the line/rectangle edge provided by [Ibrahim Mahrir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9867451/ibrahim-mahrir):

[image]

Comment: The width and height default to 300 and 150 when not specified. Why would that affect where the stroked rectangle is being drawn?

Comment: I mean, sure you can achieve symmetry in this case by setting the width and height to 100 to avoid drawing the extra bits of the rectangle on the right and bottom, but that still doesn't explain this behaviour or a potential fix to a scenario like this where the canvas size cannot be constrained to a size of **(100x100)**.

Comment: Here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpM88.png) I've just made to include in my (unfinished) answer. It's too late now, so feel free to add it to your answer. :)

Comment: @DacreDenny yes, this was the answer I was looking for.